# Get data from Power bi using REST API (not meta-data)

Tags: rest, office365, powerbi, office365api

I'm successfully able to connect to power bi.

When i use the route https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229 , i get only the meta data like name, configuredBy, isRefreshable ...

```
{
  "id": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
  "name": "SalesMarketing",
  "addRowsAPIEnabled": false,
  "configuredBy": "john@contoso.com",
  "isRefreshable": true,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRequired": true,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired": true,
  "isOnPremGatewayRequired": false
}
```

How can i get data from an existing table in my dashboard and not only the structure, which route should i use ? is it possible ?

Can i create a new table with json (POST) and get data as response ?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Power BI REST API [does not support reading data](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Can-t-reach-Tables-Columns-Relationships-of-a-DataSet/idc-p/190127#M8804) in datasets. You can only [`POST` or `DELETE` rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets) in datasets. You can find the relevant idea [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7775832-rest-api-access-to-read-datasets).

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdataset) documentation for creating new datasets.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it's bad to have an API to write data without being able to read them. I hope they ll add this functionality in the new updates