# How to connect to POWER BI DATSET in Azure data factory

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory

We have a requirement where we have to fetch data from Power BI dataset and transform the data and then produce the data again in Power BI Workspace so that I may consume that in PBI.

-> Is there any way I may connect my Power BI Dataset in ADF.

-> Once the data is fetched can I use Power Query to work on dataset in ADF.

-> Where to store that data: in ADLS or in Azure BLOB or may I save this data in SQL directly?

-> Once I have transformed the data can i publish my gold data in Power BI Workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is PowerBI REST API to execute queries:
Datasets – Execute Queries

you can access the power bi dataset via managed identity or service principal authentication.

My blog :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/11/03/copy-data-from-power-bi-through-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline-via-managed-identity-authentication-part-4/

You can leverage Dataflows to do the transformation

The query w.r.t 3rd aspect really depends on your architecture.You can preserve it anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So once i have the dataset with me in dataflow may I use SQL scripts to do the transformation on dataset or power query is only option?

Comment: can you be clear w.r.t ask?
Is your ask that once you have extracted data from Powerbi dataset, post that how can you do data transformation on that data?

Comment: Yes, how we can  do the data transformation as far as I know API will send data as in JSON and we can store in SQL and then perform the transformation. Is there any option that we store this dataset in ADF in such a way so that i can run power query to perform transformation.

Comment: You can do multiple data transformations within ADF using either dataflows in ADF or power query feature in flow between the source and sink.

Comment: Tahnks for reply. I was reading some articles and found the APIs only support the meta data retrieval but i would need the exact data. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142685/get-data-from-power-bi-using-rest-api-not-meta-data not sure if PBI is supporting the data retrieval as well.

Comment: There are different APIs, The one mentioned by you in the link is for meta data. To extarct the data there is another API.  refer this: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Extract-data-from-PowerBi-into-csv-file-in-automated-way/m-p/2994684#M40525

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have read the API document I see there is data limit for data retrieval with DAX. like 15 MB per query (120 query per min.). I was wondering how would I get data from my dataset as the size may be in GB.